# Как отследить один край открытого пути в SVG

Tags: html5, svg

Я пытаюсь сделать веб-страницу, которая позволяет пользователю рисовать линии в изображении SVG

Часть рисунка в порядке, но каждая линия должна иметь метку, которая заполняет ширину линии (линии шириной 15 пикселей).

Я пытался использовать `<textpath>`, ссылаясь на линию, которую они нарисовали, но базовая линия метки заканчивается по середине линии. Вот [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvjP.png), чтобы показать, что я имею в виду.

Я пробовал различные способы слегка подтолкнуть текст, используя  свойства CSS, но единственный успех, который у меня был, - это использовать преобразование, которое часто приводит к 'spilling out' «вываливанию» текста за пределы линии, если направление линии принимает внезапный поворот.

Другое решение, которое я попробовал, состоит в том, чтобы сгенерировать второй путь, который проходит по одному краю пути, нарисованного пользователем, и использовать его для , но я изо всех сил пытаюсь найти способ перевести нарисованные пользователем точки пути в точки, которые соответствуют отрисованному краю линии.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53784816/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Я понимаю, что линии должны иметь метку, которая заполняет ширину линии (линии шириной 15 пикселей).

- Для перемещения текста я использую `dy ="4"`

```css
text{fill:white;stroke:none;font-family:consolas;}
path{stroke-width:15px;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250"></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" dy="4">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
      </textPath>
    </text>
  

</svg>
```

- Другой вариант использует `dominant-baseline = "middle"`

```css
text{fill:white;stroke:none;font-family:consolas;}
path{stroke-width:15px;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250" ></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" 
     dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

[Ответ:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785778/7394871) @enxaneta

Answer (score 2):

### Анимация текста

Чтобы анимировать движение текста вдоль пути применяется команда
 `<animate  attributeName="startOffset"` которая принимает значения отступов текста  от начала пути и конца пути.

```css
text {
fill:yellow;
stroke:none;
font-family:consolas;
}
path {
stroke-width:15px;
fill:none;
 }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250" ></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" 
     dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
   <animate 
    attributeName="startOffset"
    dur="5s"
    repeatCount="1"
    values="0%;60%"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/> 
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

**Пример реверсного движения текста**

Устанавливаются значения отступов от начала;конца;начала  `values="0%;60%;0"`

```css
text {
fill:yellow;
stroke:none;
font-family:consolas;
}
path {
stroke-width:15px;
fill:none;
 }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250" ></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" 
     dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
   <animate 
    attributeName="startOffset"
    dur="8s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    values="0%;60%;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/> 
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Пример реверсного движения с паузами в контрольных точках

`values="0%;30%;30%;60%;60%;0%;0%"`

```css
text {
fill:yellow;
stroke:none;
font-family:consolas;
font-weight:500;
}
path {
stroke-width:15px;
fill:none;
 }
```

```html
 <svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250" ></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" 
     dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
   <animate 
    attributeName="startOffset"
    dur="10s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    values="0%;30%;30%;60%;60%;0%;0%"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/> 
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Ответ : @Alexandr_TT